# If there are four bakeries that each close one day a week, how many schedules are possible if at least one bakery is open each day?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I’m self studying for a probabilities and statistic exam so unfortunately, i don’t have anyone to ask. So the question goes, we have 4 bakeries and 7 days in a week. Each bakery closes once a week.

a) How many possibilities are there? Several bakeries may close on the same day.

I answered this with: $7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7= 2401$.

b) at most one bakery can close on any day.

I answered with: $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$.

c) at least one bakery needs to be open on each day.

Here I am struggling, so any help is much much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  You should explain how you arrived at your answers so that readers can detect any errors you may have made.  That said, your answers to the first two questions are correct.

Comment: Suggestion for c):  Ask yourself how many schedules are possible in which all the bakeries are closed on the same day.

Comment: Thank you Taussig for the warm welcome! :)

Comment: awkward, this would be 7 schedules in which all bakeries are closed on the same day? ( aka all closed on Monday, all closed on Tuesday, etc). Now I’m confused what do I do with this info haha. I even reduced the number of bakeries to 2 and the days to 3 to try to to draw the possible combinations and ended up with 6 so I’m utterly confused

Answer (score 1):

- We need the no of possible schedules where each bakery closes on any one day of the week and atleast one bakery is open every day.
- In part A, you found all the schedules possible, but that number contained the days when all bakery are closed.
- Note-**(number of schedules when atleast one bakery is open)+(number of schedules when all bakeries are closed one same day)=(All possible Schedules).**
- Also, as there are 7 days in the week, possible no. of schedules when all bakeries are closed on same day=7.
- Thus, answer = $7^4 - 7$